# Search string data with special characters removed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, string-searching

We have a table with ~6 million of products:

| ID | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | 123.456.789-M |
| 2 | Two | 852.789456 |
| 3 | Three | 1-123654.P |

What is a good way (with regards to performance) to filter products by code column without masks (traces, slashes or dots)?

Example:

```
SELECT id, name FROM products WHERE code = '123456789M' OR code = '1123654P';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an indexed computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
    ID integer NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED,
    [Name] varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    Code varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    SearchCode AS 
        ISNULL(
            CONVERT(varchar(20), 
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(Code, '-', ''), 
                    '.', '')
                ), 
            ''),
    
    INDEX [IX dbo.Products SearchCode (Name)] 
        (SearchCode) 
        INCLUDE ([Name])
);

INSERT dbo.Products
    (ID, [Name], Code)
VALUES
    (1, 'One', '123.456.789-M'),
    (2, 'Two', '852.789456'),
    (3, 'Three', '1-123654.P');
```

```
SELECT P.ID, P.[Name]
FROM dbo.Products AS P
WHERE P.SearchCode = '123456789M';
```

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | One |

[image: plan]

[db<>fiddle online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99b2c9cd7f65d3ba5fd54e5cb377e30a)